# Error to edit the registry in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dql

I have a relation between 2 tables `Orders` and`Users` and the information is displayed correctly.

Mapping Users:

```
BackendBundle\Entity\Users:
type: entity
table: users
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        column: ID
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    username:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    yourname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    firstname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    lastname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    middlename:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 10
        options:
            fixed: false
    address:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
    address2:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
    apartment:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    pobox:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    city:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    state:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    zipcode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 100
        options:
            fixed: false
    country:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    countrycode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 2
        options:
            fixed: false
    phone:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    fax:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 150
        options:
            fixed: false
    email:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    password:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
    company:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        options:
            fixed: false
    type:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 0
    datein:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Mapping Orders:

```
BackendBundle\Entity\Orders:
type: entity
table: orders
indexes:
    fk_order_user1_idx:
        columns:
            - user_id
id:
    orderid:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        column: OrderID
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    orderdate:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        column: OrderDate
    ordernumber:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: OrderNumber
    customername:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 250
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CustomerName
    customeraddress:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CustomerAddress
    countrycode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 2
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CountryCode
    shippingaddress:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingAddress
    status:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: Status
    subtotal:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: SubTotal
    shippingcost:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: ShippingCost
    tax:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: Tax
    discount:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: Discount
    totalorder:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 2
        column: TotalOrder
    shippingcarrier:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingCarrier
    shippingtype:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingType
    shippingtrackingnumber:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingTrackingNumber
    paymentmethod:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: PaymentMethod
    paymentapproval:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 100
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: PaymentApproval
    cc:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 20
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CC
    ccexp:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 10
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CCExp
    ccv:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 10
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: CCV
    memo:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 500
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: Memo
    sessionid:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: SessionID
    discountcode:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: DiscountCode
    hasshipgift:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
        column: HasShipGift
    message:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 300
        options:
            fixed: false
    imagen:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        options:
            unsigned: false
    siteType:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 50
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: site_type
    shippingname:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 250
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: ShippingName
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: Users
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            user_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I need to edit a record of orders so I put the following code in the list:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{path('edit_orderlist',{ 'id': ordenes.orderid })}}">Edit</a></td>
```

But the moment it arrives at the controller I have with this code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $orders_repo=$em->getRepository("BackendBundle:Orders");
    $order=$orders_repo->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
```

It shows me this error:

> Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "BackendBundle\Entity\Users"

`Orders` has `OrderId` primary key and Users as primary key`id`

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us the mapping of your Users class ?

Comment: Yes, I add mapping in the question

Answer (score 0):

After investigating and reading the different recommendations, the problem was in the .yml files of the tables and in the Entities, Symfony show this error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

To verify this create a test environment and perform the import and creation of entities to check for any errors.

Here's the code:

```
//BackendBundle\Entity\Orders:
type: entity
table: orders
indexes:
    fk_Orders_Users_idx:
        columns:
            - Users_ID
......
manyToOne:
    users:
        targetEntity: Users
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            Users_ID:
                referencedColumnName: ID
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

`Users.orm.yml` is the same as before

Another change is in the Entity `Orders.php`

```
/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
private $users;
.........
/**
 * Set users
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Users $users
 *
 * @return Orders
 */
public function setUsers(\BackendBundle\Entity\Users $users = null)
{
    $this->users = $users;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get users
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}
```

With these changes everything works well.